# How to make the thing workable for text contained within <li>?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Following is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3LXR/7/

The tool-tip is not appearing if I use text in the `<li>` but the same thing is working if I use `<img>` as follows:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/66nLy/17/)

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<li class='tooltip'>
    Your text goes here
    <ul class="tooltipText">
        <li class='info'>Some text to fill the box with.</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Change your code to use li instead of div, and then if you have problem post question here.

Comment: @RohitAwasthi:I've changed the code and uploaded the fiddle. But still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the info div with another div having class tooltipText

Code:

```
 <div class="tooltipText">
    <div class='info'>
       Some text to fill the box with.
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66nLy/19/

Changed the js function line:

```
 elem.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', click);
```

to

```
 elem.querySelector('span').addEventListener('click', click);
```

Comment: You can see from the fiddle that I'm not using <div> I'm using <li> and I don't want to use <div> at all.

Comment: @PHPGeek: Updated the fiddle please check the same

Answer (score 0):

First error made is the JavaScript execution moment of in the provided jsfiddle. The Working fiddle uses `no wrap - in <head>`, the non working fiddle is using `onLoad`. As you are binding the event handler on load, this event will already be executed when the JavaScript is running so no handler can be bound.

Second you have the wrong selector (still `img` altough there's no such tag. To simplify I put the text in `span` and chose this span as selector, see this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3LXR/11/

HTML

```
<li class='tooltip'>
    <span>Your text goes here</span>
    <ul class="tooltipText">
        <li class='info'>Some text to fill the box with.</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JavaScript

```
elem.querySelector('span').addEventListener('click', click);
```